# Legal issues with Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, finance

I'm confused with why people claim that current legal system cannot handle any wrongdoings of algorithms that involve Machine Learning and Artificial Intelligence. The claim is that it is impossible to find who is liable for the wrongdoing. This claim seems strange: isn't it obvious that it's the company who developed the algorithm that is liable for any issues that this algorithm caused? Can someone explain where the current legal system/framework/laws break down when it comes to any harm caused by Machine Learning applications?

Comment: You say it’s obviously the company that’s responsible. Who at Tesla is responsible when one of their cars crashes? Is it Elon Musk? Is it the lead engineer? Is it the engineer who designed the specific piece that malfunctioned? // This is an interesting question but probably not appropriate for this Stack. The best option is probably Law, perhaps Artificial Intelligence.

Comment: Definitely something for [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/)! The corresponding question on Law can be [found here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74396/artificial-intelligence-and-law).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been cross-posted here https://law.stackexchange.com/q/74396